# Rotate image in google talk and skype

Tags: webcam

In my computer I have an app's camera and GTK UVC video viwer, I can use it without problems, but when I use hangouts or Skype my image is inverted.
are there any way to create a virtual camera where i can rotate the image and use it in skype or hangouts?
In windows there are a software manycam, where you have a virtual camera, change what you want, and use this camera in skype or any other app.

Any option to solve it?